# Get Trial balance of certain date with Dynamics-nav Soap Web Service

Tags: web-services, soap, navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I created a portal and reporting tools based on the SOAP web service of Microsoft Dynamics Navision 2015, it seems not possible to get the balance of all general ledger accounts of a certain date by teh Web Service. For example I want the Trial Balance of december 31, 2015. With Page 16, you can get the current chart of account with the balance, in Navision on that page you are able to set a Limits Total Filter.

Does anyone know how I can get this trial balance for a certain date?

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't set the FlowFilters using the Standard NAV Page webservices the only way to archive this is to build a custom Codeunit WebService where you can pass the Date Filter, the code inside the Codeunit can apply the FlowFilter, calculate the FlowField and return it.

Cheers